# How to read multiple files that are in subdirectory of wd in R?

Tags: r

Here is a functions that I have:

```
files <- list.files(path = "",pattern = ".txt")  
do.call(cbind,
  lapply(files, function(x) setnames(fread(x, select = 2), x)))
```

The problem with this is that I need to make several lists of files where each group of text files are contained and then apply do.call function for all of these lists separately, which seems very inconvenient. There must be a way to create just one function, that takes first two arguments path and pattern and then applies them to fread or read.csv function.
In my case, I need to change working directories each time I would like to read a list of files in a specific folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to read *all* sub-directories of `wd/path`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas No, just specific ones. In fact, I've seen a very simple function within a function on this same website that does exactly what I'd like. But unfortunately, I cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Within a specific sub-directory:

```
subdir <- "sub_directory_name"
files <- list.files(path = subdir, pattern = ".txt", full.names = T)  
names(files) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))
do.call(cbind, sapply(files, fread, select = 2))
```

For multiple sub-directories:

```
sub_dirs <- c("sub_directory_name01", "sub_directory_name02")
# sub_dirs <- list.dirs(recursive = F) # for all sub-directories in wd

sapply(sub_dirs, function(subdir){
  files <- list.files(path = subdir, pattern = ".txt", full.names = T)  
  names(files) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))
  do.call(cbind, sapply(files, fread, select = 2, simplity = F))
}, simplify = F)
```

Note that `names(files)` is unnecessary here, once you're using `cbind` on them.

---

**Edit:**

Based in the another answer, I just realized you wanna a function.
To wrap it inside a function:

```r
read_subdir <- function(sub_dirs, pattern) {
  sapply(sub_dirs, function(subdir){
    files <- list.files(path = subdir, pattern = pattern, full.names = T)  
    do.call(cbind, lapply(files, fread, select = 2))
  }, simplify = F)
}
```

---

**Tests:**

```r
# Create folder and file examples
library(data.table)
sapply(c("dir01", "dir02"), dir.create)
sapply(1:3, function(i) {
  fwrite(iris, paste0("dir01/iris", i, ".csv"))
  fwrite(iris, paste0("dir02/iris", i, ".csv"))
})
```

It creates the following folder-file structure:

```sh
.
├── dir01
│   ├── iris1.csv
│   ├── iris2.csv
│   └── iris3.csv
└── dir02
    ├── iris1.csv
    ├── iris2.csv
    └── iris3.csv
```

Test with within one subfolder:

```r
> str(read_subdir('dir01', 'csv$'))
List of 1
 $ dir01:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Test with multiple subfolders

```r
> str(read_subdir(c('dir01', 'dir02'), 'csv$'))
List of 2
 $ dir01:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ dir02:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Test with pattern that doesn't exist

```r
> str(read_subdir(c('dir01', 'dir02'), 'asdf$'))
List of 2
 $ dir01: NULL
 $ dir02: NULL
```

**Identifying column origin with file's suffix:**

If you decides to use `sapply` instead of lapply in the function, like the second code chunk I've provided:

```r
read_subdir_sapply <- function(sub_dirs, pattern) {
  sapply(sub_dirs, function(subdir) {
    files <- list.files(path = subdir, pattern = pattern, full.names = T)  
    names(files) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))
    do.call(cbind, sapply(files, fread, select = 2, simplify = F))
  }, simplify = F)
}
```

then you'll get column names with the file names as prefix, see:

```r
> str(read_subdir_sapply('dir01', 'csv$'))
List of 1
 $ dir01:Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ iris1.Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ iris2.Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ iris3.Sepal.Width: num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like the function below does what the question asks for. Untested, since I don't have the files to test it.

```
readSubdir <- function(path, pattern, select = 2, recursive = FALSE){
  wd <- normalizePath(".")
  fp <- file.path(wd, path)
  files <- list.files(path = fp, pattern = pattern, 
                      recursive = recursive, 
                      full.names = TRUE)
  data_list <- lapply(files, data.table::fread, select = select)
  names(file_list) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))
  list(files = files, data = data_list)
}
```

Comment: I provided some test files. There're a couple of issues here. For instance, `files` doens't  show the subdir path, you're better using `full.names = T`. For `lapply`, try removing `function(x)` or using `function(x) data.table::fread(x, select = select)`. With such modification, it works great! And it also provides a distinct organized output from my answer, maybe it's what the OP wants. +1

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva You are twice right, thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Vroom does this automatically:

```
library(vroom)
vroom('<path to directory>')
```